# Why am I allowed to take back my upvote?

Tags: discussion, support, voting

If I upvoted an answer, after some time I can't take back my vote because it's locked and it's not for me to take back until the answer is edited again.

but I can edit it myself and then take back my upvote,

am I really allowed to do this? edit it myself and take my vote back??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a known "feature".

> am I really allowed to do this?

Yes, in the sense that we all know about it and you're not prevented from doing it. Don't tell anyone though.... keep it our little secret.

While it might seem odd, you would be surprised how little you actually need to do that - I've done it maybe twice in five years, IIRC the first time was because I voted the wrong way by accident, the second because I originally misunderstood the question. Note that it works both ways - you can also reverse down votes.

This has also been discussed before: [Should we allow our edits to reverse our own upvotes and downvotes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109859/146015)

Comment: I do this a lot!

Comment: @tinybyte, maybe you need to consider your votes more carefully.. it makes sense removing a down vote after you've edited an answer into shape. But it's not a great experience for the OP if they see some token edit by you and a -10.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a scenario that makes the feature make sense as-is.

I am browsing along my favorite tag ([google-visualization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-visualization)). I come across a bad question. Now usually I'd edit it, but I don't have time. So I vote to close, toss on a downvote, and go to my *"Make millions by starting a Mung Bean farm"* seminar. When I come back, I see that the post is still in awful shape, but because my favorite tag is not frequented so often, I still have the only vote, and nobody else has helped me with the closing.

Since I'm all excited about being able to quit my day job due to my newfound career in Mung Bean farming, I sit down and edit that post in to shape. I realize after the edit that the post really isn't bad, it just needed some love, and I really want to know the answer. So I reverse that downvote and retract my close vote, and start creating my dashboard application to monitor my Mung Bean growing process with my newfound knowledge.

This is good, and we should encourage it.